# Maximum input number value in my form

Tags: forms, input

I am try to setup the max number to 10 in this form [enter link description here](http://skiathosvillahermes.com/index.html)

Please how it is possible to do that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add a validation in your code:

```
   $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
            // Stop acting like a button
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the field name
            fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
            // Get its current value
            var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
            // If is not undefined
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < 10) {
                // Increment
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
            } else {
                // Otherwise put a 0 there
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(1);
            }
        });
```